# MSBuild Tasks Execution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

VS 2010 - .Net 4.0

In my .csproj file if I dropped the following code at the bottom of the file inside the  tag why would it not run?

```
<Target Name="FooBared" >
<Message Text="Hello from FooBar" />
</Target>
```

I am trying to understand what makes a target execute. I have a .targets file with a target in it that is getting imported into the proj file and it runs just fine.

I have another .targets file with a target in it with no condition and it will not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Change the importance of the Message task.  [Add Importance="High" to the message task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy0yx8d.aspx).

2)  'FooBared' is not a default build target.  You'll either need to pass "/t:FooBared" to your msbuild.exe command, or cause that target to execute using [DependsOnTargets, AfterTargets, or BeforeTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee216359.aspx).